# Generating a random complex-valued tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I need to generate a random vector  as follows:

```
Y = (np.random.randn(tf.size(signal)) + 1j * np.random.randn(tf.size(signal)))
```

Where the variable `signal` is a vector representing the output of a neural network,  but I get an error as below:

```
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1422, in mtrand.RandomState.randn
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1552, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 167, in mtrand.cont0_array
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have also tried `signal.shape`  , but also the same error is appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TF1.x and TF2.x: Doing the operation in TensorFlow

When working with tensorflow's tensor, you should use primarily the `tf` API. In your case, you can simply use :

```
Y = tf.complex(tf.random.normal((tf.size(signal),)), tf.random.normal((tf.size(signal),)))
```

This will return a random `complex64` tensor with the real and imaginary part following the normal distribution.

### TF2.x: Eager execution

If you need to work directly with numpy, you can use the `numpy` method to evaluate your tensor in **eager execution**:

```
Y = (np.random.randn(tf.size(signal).numpy()) + 1j * np.random.randn(tf.size(signal).numpy()))
```

### TF1.x: evaluating your Tensor with a `tf.Session`

You actually need to evaluate your tensor inside a `tf.Session` to get the output as a numpy array, by doing a call to [`tf.Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run):

```
get_size_op = tf.size(signal)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you might need to provide a dictionary containing 
    # the values for your placeholders (feed_dict keyword argument)
    size_signal = sess.run(get_size_op)

# size_signal is an integer you can use in the numpy function
Y = (np.random.randn(size_signal) + 1j * np.random.randn(size_signal))
```

**Note:** It's probably better to evaluate `signal` in the session and continue the rest of your computation with numpy (using `signal.size` instead of `tf.size(signal)`)

---

**Note**: the equivalent of `tensor.shape` is `tf.shape`. I used `tf.size` because it is what you are using in your question.

Comment: I need to work directly with numpy, but when I use your second suggestion I get an erro of `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'` and when I try using `tf.enable_eager_execution()`, it gives me another error `raise RuntimeError("tf.placeholder() is not compatible with "
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution`.

Comment: You are using tf 1.x then, am I correct? Could you add the definition of `signal` in your question?

Comment: Yes, I am using tensorflow  1.15. What you mean by definition? signal is a vector representing the output of neural network. I mean the output of neural network is called signal.

Comment: I added an example on how to do with TF1.x. I think you might need to read some documentation to figure out how TensorFlow 1.x works.